# undefined variable and invalid argument supplied

Tags: php, mysqli

This is strange ubt if I select a an individual student from a drop down menu, (if the `$_POST['student'] != 0` as value `0` represents an `All` option and all other options have their own numbers`), I get an error stating:

`Notice: Undefined variable: questions in ... on line 597 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ... on line 597`

My question is what is causing this error and how can it be fixed?

Code is below which I have tried to reduce as much as possible, near the bottom of code snippet is where error line is which is commented:

```
    $selectedstudentanswerqry = "
        SELECT
        sa.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname
    ...
        FROM Student st
    ...
        ";

        // Initially empty
            $where = array('q.SessionId = ?');
            $parameters = array($_POST["session"]);
            $parameterTypes = 'i';


        //check if POST is empty

        // Check whether a specific student was selected

        $p_student = empty($_POST["student"])?0:$_POST["student"];  // Now if $_POST['student'] is either 0 or empty $p_student will be 0
        switch($p_student){
        case 0:
            //dont' add where filters
            break;
        default:
            $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
            $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
            $parameterTypes .= 'i';
        }

        // Check whether a specific question was selected
        $p_question = empty($_POST["question"])?0:$_POST["question"]; // Same here, if $_POST['question'] is either 0 or empty $p_question will be 0
            switch($p_question){
        case 0:
            //dont' add where filters 
            break;
        default:
            $where[] = 'q.QuestionId = ?';
            $parameters[] .= $_POST["question"];
            $parameterTypes .= 'i';
        }
        // If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
        // our query
        if(!empty($where)) {
            $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
            // You only need to call bind_param once
    }




        $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
          GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
          ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
        ";


    global $mysqli;
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);

    if (count($where) == 1) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0]);
        }
        else if (count($where) == 2) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
        }
        else if (count($where) == 3) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1], $parameters[2]);
        }

    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); 
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentId,$detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname); 

    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->store_result();
    $selectedstudentanswernum = $selectedstudentanswerstmt->num_rows(); 

        $arrStudentId = array();
        $arrStudentAlias = array();
     ...

        while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {

        //Check if the student data exist.
        if (!isset($questions[$detailsStudentId])) {
            $questions[$detailsStudentId] = array(
                'studentalias' => $detailsStudentAlias,
                'studentforename' => $detailsStudentForename,
                'studentsurname' => $detailsStudentSurname,
                'questions' => array()
            );
        }

        $questions[$detailsStudentId]['questions'][$detailsQuestionId] = array(
            'questionno'=>$detailsQuestionNo,
            'content'=>$detailsQuestionContent,
    .....
        );
    }

    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->close();
    ?>

//LINE 597 ERROR BELOW
    foreach ($questions as $studentId => $studentData) {
        echo '<hr><h3>'.$studentData['studentalias'].' - '.$studentData['studentforename'].' '.$studentData['studentsurname'].'</h3>';

        foreach ($studentData['questions'] as $questionId => $questionData) {
            echo '<h3>'.$questionData['questionno'].': '.$questionData['content'].'</h3>';
    }
    }
```

Comment: Since you just posted parts of your source, the definition might be within a if statement or a never executed loop. Look for that

Comment: @Benny that is pretty much the problem, am I suppose to be looking for a braacket or a colon or what am I suppose to look for exactly? The `...` in my code snippet is just like an etc for long lists of code, it does not contain any brackets or anything like that, it is just to make the code look smaller if you know what I mean. The structure you see is exactly the same structure as the full code

Comment: For example look for all occurences of `$questions`, or at least put them in here because its the important part and it was propably skipped in your example. Or check if `while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch())` is looped at least once, otherwise questions could be null

Answer (score 0):

The initialized of the variable $questions itself could be the problem. Look through your code and see where something like `$questions =` is called. Probably it is everytime within a not run if statement.

If you call:

```
$questions[...]
```

and never initialized `$questions` as an array you will also have problems.
So you need to initialize `$questions` with:

```
$questions = array();
```

after this you will have no problems accessing fields of the array.

Comment: `$questions[...]` i would rather say "may also have problems" in some versions of php it works as expected, in some it behaves unexpectedly

Comment: yep, sure but that is why you should initialize it ;) but thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Benny wheredo I place`$questions = array();` because above while loop it does not output any data and in while loop above the first if statement and it still displays error

Comment: yah, sure because it initializes an empty array. so you want to place it before doing anything else with `$questions` and of course outside any if statements that could not be run.

Comment: But it still gives me error when I do this, the first instance $questions is called is here ` if (!isset($questions[$detailsStudentId])) {...` which is in the code snippet in question. I place `$questions = array();` above this line but still get same errors

Comment: try `var_dump($questions);` and `var_dump($questions[$detailsStudentId]);` right before the code fails and tell us the information

Comment: @Benny It is ok, i know what has happended, it is because I selected a student who has not yet answered the question, hence the undefined variable, if I selected a student who did complete the questions then they are fine